# Read text file and check for value in a specific position and change when true

Tags: powershell

I need to loop through multiple text files and check for a $ value in position 7 on each line of text and replace it with an * when found. But ONLY when it is in position 7. I do not want to change it if it is found in other positions. This is as far as I have gotten. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\*.txt' -Recurse | 
        foreach $line in Get-Content $_  {
        $linePosition1to5 = $line.Substring(0,6)
        $linePosition7    = $line.Substring(6,1)  
        $linePositionRest = $line.Substring(8)  
        if($linePosition7 = "$"){
           $linePosition7 = "*"  
            }
        $linePosition1to5 +  $linePosition7 + $linePositionRest |
     Set-Content $_
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some examples of the text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there something that doesn't work in your example, or just that all the nested substrings are annoying to work with?

I'd use regex for this one. e.g.

```
$Lines = Get-Content -Path "C:\examplefile.txt" -raw

$Lines -replace '(?m)(^.{6})\$', '$1*'
```

To explain the regex:

`?m` indicates that it's multiline, required because I used raw get-content rather than pulling an array. Array would work too, just needs a loop like you did.

`^.{6}` line start plus any 6 characters (capture group 1)
`\$` escaped dollar character

`$1*` Capture group 1 left as is, dollar replaced with `*`, anything else not captured and therefore left untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for code and the explanation. I realized that I left out the -raw option and it did work. Putting it back in it seems to add a line to the end of each file. Unless you can think of reason why I shouldn't I was going to leave it out.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\TEST\*.txt' -Recurse | ForEach {
     (Get-Content $_ | ForEach   { $_ -replace '(?m)(^.{6})\$', '$1*'}) |
     Set-Content $_
}
```

Comment: -raw gets you a single string containing the entire content. Otherwise you get an array with one line per member. So with raw you don't need the foreach. You can get rid of the multiline flag if doing it with an array instead.

Comment: With the accepted solution based on `Get-Content -Raw`, simply add `-NoNewLine` to the `Set-Content` call to prevent an extra trailing newline.